# How to ensure div tag is present in between 2 other tags

Tags: selenium

Please find the attached screenshot:

[image]

In the attached screenshot I need to ensure that the selected div tag is present after the `<section class="hp_news">`.

What is the logic I need to use for this?

Comment: Does it have to immediately below it?

Comment: If so you can use xpath with position - '//section[@class='hp......']/following-sibling::div[@id='..........' and position()=1]'

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code to verify weather `<div>` tag after the specific section

```
List<WebElement> ads = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//section[@class='hp_news']/following::div[@class='AdUnit']"));
if(ads.size()>0)
{
    System.out.println("add available");
 }
 else
 {
        System.out.println("not available");
  }
```

use the `following-sibling` method of xpath  which will locate you `<div>` based on the `<section>` tag having `class = "hp_news"`

Comment: @prasanth kotagiri, nice to hear :)  if it is helpful then don't forget to `accept` the answer

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the selected div tag is present after the `<section class="hp_news">`:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//section[@class='hp_news']/following::div[@class='AdUnit']")))
{
    System.out.println("div is present");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("div is not present");
}
```